# Fully-functioning chess game in Python

Tags: python, game, console, chess

This post is in succession to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282145/text-based-chess-game-in-python). I have implemented all functionalities like castling, en-passant, pawn promotion etc. 50 move rule and 3-move repetition is pending.

I would like my code to be reviewed before going to the AI (simple) part of the project.
I would appreciate any improvements and also bugs found.

Run the `console_ui.py` file to play chess!

White is at the bottom and black is at the top.
Uppercase characters represent white pieces and lowercase represent black.

### utility.py

```
from enum import Enum

# Piece and board related stuff
START_MATRIX = [
    ["R", "N", "B", "Q", "K", "B", "N", "R"],
    ["P"] * 8,
    ["."] * 8,
    ["."] * 8,
    ["."] * 8,
    ["."] * 8,
    ["p"] * 8,
    ["r", "n", "b", "q", "k", "b", "n", "r"]
]

class Color(Enum):
    NONE = 0
    WHITE = 1
    BLACK = 2

def get_color(piece: str) -> bool:
    if piece == ".":
        return Color.NONE
    elif piece.isupper():
        return Color.WHITE
    return Color.BLACK
def get_opposite_color(color: Color) -> Color:
    if color == Color.WHITE:
        return Color.BLACK
    elif color == Color.BLACK:
        return Color.WHITE
    return color.NONE
def is_white(piece: str) -> bool:
    return get_color(piece) == Color.WHITE
def is_black(piece: str) -> bool:
    return get_color(piece) == Color.BLACK
def is_empty(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece == "."


def is_king(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "k"
def is_queen(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "q"
def is_rook(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "r"
def is_bishop(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "b"
def is_knight(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "n"
def is_pawn(piece: str) -> bool:
    return piece.lower() == "p"


# Piece movement related stuff

def is_in_bounds(*nums: int):
    return all([0 <= num <= 7 for num in nums])

class MoveType(Enum):
    NORMAL = 0
    SHORT_CASTLE = 1
    LONG_CASTLE = 2
    PAWN_PROMOTION = 3

FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP = {
    "a": 0, "b": 1, "c": 2, "d": 3,
    "e": 4, "f": 5, "g": 6, "h": 7
}
INDEX_TO_FILE_MAP = {v: k for k, v in FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP.items()}

def encode_move(move: dict) -> str:
    # Normal move: e2e4
    if move["type"] == MoveType.NORMAL:
        start_y, start_x = move["start_pos"]
        end_y, end_x = move["end_pos"]
        return (
            INDEX_TO_FILE_MAP[start_x] + str(start_y + 1)
            + INDEX_TO_FILE_MAP[end_x] + str(end_y + 1)
        )
    elif move["type"] == MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION:
        start_y, start_x = move["start_pos"]
        end_y, end_x = move["end_pos"]
        return (
            INDEX_TO_FILE_MAP[start_x] + str(start_y + 1)
            + INDEX_TO_FILE_MAP[end_x] + str(end_y + 1)
            + "=" + move["promoted_piece"]
        )
    # Short castle: 0-0
    elif move["type"] == MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE:
        return "0-0"
    # Long castle: 0-0-0
    elif move["type"] == MoveType.LONG_CASTLE:
        return "0-0-0"
    # Pawn promotion: ToDo

def decode_move(move: str) -> dict:
    # Normal move: e2e4
    if len(move) == 4:
        return {
            "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
            "start_pos": [int(move[1]) - 1, FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP[move[0]]],
            "end_pos": [int(move[3]) - 1, FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP[move[2]]],
        }
    # Pawn Promotion: e7e8=q
    elif len(move) == 6:
        return {
            "type": MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION,
            "start_pos": [int(move[1]) - 1, FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP[move[0]]],
            "end_pos": [int(move[3]) - 1, FILE_TO_INDEX_MAP[move[2]]],
            "promoted_piece": move[5]
        }
    # Short castle: 0-0
    elif move == "0-0":
        return {
            "type": MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE
        }
    # Long castle: 0-0-0
    elif move == "0-0-0":
        return {
            "type": MoveType.LONG_CASTLE
        }
    # Pawn promotion: ToDo

KNIGHT_DELTAS = [
    # delta_y, delta_x
    [2, 1], [1, 2],
    [-2, 1], [-1, 2],
    [1, -2], [2, -1],
    [-1, -2], [-2, -1]
]
BISHOP_DELTAS = [
    # delta_y, delta_x
    [1, 1], [-1, -1],
    [-1, 1], [1, -1]
]
ROOK_DELTAS = [
    # delta_y, delta_x
    [1, 0], [0, 1],
    [-1, 0], [0, -1]
]
QUEEN_DELTAS = BISHOP_DELTAS + ROOK_DELTAS
KING_DELTAS = [
    # delta_y, delta_x
    [1, 0], [0, 1],
    [-1, 0], [0, -1],
    [1, 1], [-1, -1],
    [-1, 1], [1, -1]
]
```

### board.py

```
from utility import *
from copy import deepcopy

class GameState(Enum):
    RUNNING = 0
    CHECKMATE = 1
    STALEMATE = 2

class Board:
    def __init__(self, matrix=None, current_turn_color=Color.WHITE) -> None:
        self.matrix = matrix
        if not matrix:
            self.matrix = START_MATRIX
        self.current_turn_color = current_turn_color
        self.game_state = GameState.RUNNING
        self.moves_history = []
        self.en_passant_squares = {
            Color.WHITE: [],
            Color.BLACK: []
        }
        self.can_castle = {
            Color.WHITE: {
                MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE: True,
                MoveType.LONG_CASTLE: True
            },
            Color.BLACK: {
                MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE: True,
                MoveType.LONG_CASTLE: True
            }
        }
        self.legal_moves = self.generate_legal_moves()

    def play_move(self, str_move: str) -> None:
        if str_move in self.legal_moves:
            move_data = decode_move(str_move)
            print("Printing en-passant squares: ", self.en_passant_squares)
            self.implement_move(move_data)
            self.en_passant_squares[self.current_turn_color] = []
            self.current_turn_color = get_opposite_color(self.current_turn_color)
            self.legal_moves = self.generate_legal_moves()
            self.moves_history.append(str_move)
            self.update_game_state()
        else:
            print(f"{str_move} not legal!! Error!!")
            return

    def update_game_state(self):
        if len(self.legal_moves) == 0:
            if self.is_check():
                self.game_state = GameState.CHECKMATE
            else:
                self.game_state = GameState.STALEMATE
        else:
            self.game_state = GameState.RUNNING

    def implement_move(self, move: dict) -> None:
        if move["type"] == MoveType.NORMAL:
            start_y, start_x = move["start_pos"]
            end_y, end_x = move["end_pos"]
            piece = self.matrix[start_y][start_x]
            self.matrix[end_y][end_x] = piece
            self.matrix[start_y][start_x] = "."
            # Prevent castle
            if is_rook(piece):
                if start_x == 7: # h1/h8 rook
                    self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE] = False
                elif start_x == 0: # a1/a8 rook
                    self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.LONG_CASTLE] = False
            # En passant
            elif is_pawn(piece):
                # If en-passant happens
                if [end_y, end_x] in self.en_passant_squares[self.current_turn_color]:
                    self.matrix[start_y][end_x] = "."
                # If black pawn moves 2 steps ahead
                if start_y - end_y == 2:
                    self.en_passant_squares[Color.WHITE].append([start_y - 1, start_x])
                # If white pawn moves 2 steps ahead
                elif start_y - end_y == -2:
                    self.en_passant_squares[Color.BLACK].append([start_y + 1, start_x])
        elif move["type"] == MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION:
            start_y, start_x = move["start_pos"]
            end_y, end_x = move["end_pos"]
            promoted_piece = move["promoted_piece"]
            if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE:
                promoted_piece = promoted_piece.upper()
            self.matrix[end_y][end_x] = promoted_piece
            self.matrix[start_y][start_x] = "."
        elif move["type"] == MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE:
            pos_y = 0 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else 7
            # Move h1/h8 rook to f1/f8
            self.matrix[pos_y][5] = self.matrix[pos_y][7]
            self.matrix[pos_y][7] = "."
            # Move e1/e8 king to g1/g8
            self.matrix[pos_y][6] = self.matrix[pos_y][4]
            self.matrix[pos_y][4] = "."
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE] = False
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.LONG_CASTLE] = False 
        elif move["type"] == MoveType.LONG_CASTLE:
            pos_y = 0 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else 7
            # Move a1/a8 rook to d1/d8
            self.matrix[pos_y][3] = self.matrix[pos_y][0]
            self.matrix[pos_y][0] = "."
            # Move e1/e8 king to c1/c8
            self.matrix[pos_y][2] = self.matrix[pos_y][4]
            self.matrix[pos_y][4] = "."
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE] = False
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.LONG_CASTLE] = False

    def get_all_pieces_pos(self, color: Color) -> list:
        pieces_pos = []
        for y, rank in enumerate(self.matrix):
            for x, piece in enumerate(rank):
                if type(piece) == int:
                    print(rank, x, piece)
                if get_color(piece) == color:
                    pieces_pos.append([y, x])
        return pieces_pos

    def generate_primitive_moves(self) -> list[str]:
        "Generates all move without validating any checks"
        primitive_moves = []
        # Normal moves
        pieces_pos = self.get_all_pieces_pos(self.current_turn_color)
        opposite_color = get_opposite_color(self.current_turn_color)
        # print("pieces_pos:", pieces_pos)
        for pos_y, pos_x in pieces_pos:
            piece = self.matrix[pos_y][pos_x]
            # print(f"pos_y: {pos_y}, pos_x: {pos_x}, piece: {piece}")
            if is_pawn(piece):
                delta_y = 1 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else -1
                # Forward 1 square
                if is_in_bounds(pos_y + delta_y) and is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y + delta_y][pos_x]):
                    if (pos_y + delta_y) in [0, 7]:
                        for promoted_piece in ["q", "r", "n", "b"]:
                            primitive_moves.append(encode_move({
                                "type": MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION,
                                "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                                "end_pos": [pos_y + delta_y, pos_x],
                                "promoted_piece": promoted_piece
                            }))
                    else:
                        primitive_moves.append(encode_move({
                            "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                            "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                            "end_pos": [pos_y + delta_y, pos_x]
                        }))
                    # Forward 2 square
                    if is_in_bounds(pos_y + 2*delta_y) and is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y + 2*delta_y][pos_x]):
                        if (
                            (self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE and pos_y == 1) or
                            (self.current_turn_color == Color.BLACK and pos_y == 6)
                        ):
                            primitive_moves.append(encode_move({
                                "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                                "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                                "end_pos": [pos_y + 2*delta_y, pos_x]
                            }))
                # Diagonal 1 square left/right
                for delta_x in [1, -1]:
                    if (
                        is_in_bounds(pos_y + delta_y, pos_x + delta_x) and
                        (
                            get_color(self.matrix[pos_y + delta_y][pos_x + delta_x]) == opposite_color or
                            [pos_y + delta_y, pos_x + delta_x] in self.en_passant_squares[self.current_turn_color]
                        )
                    ):
                        if (pos_y + delta_y) in [0, 7]:
                            for promoted_piece in ["q", "r", "n", "b"]:
                                primitive_moves.append(encode_move({
                                    "type": MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION,
                                    "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                                    "end_pos": [pos_y + delta_y, pos_x + delta_x],
                                    "promoted_piece": promoted_piece
                                }))
                        else:
                            primitive_moves.append(encode_move({
                                "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                                "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                                "end_pos": [pos_y + delta_y, pos_x + delta_x]
                            }))
            elif is_knight(piece):
                primitive_moves += self.generate_knight_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
            elif is_bishop(piece):
                primitive_moves += self.generate_bishop_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
            elif is_rook(piece):
                primitive_moves += self.generate_rook_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
            elif is_queen(piece):
                primitive_moves += self.generate_queen_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
            elif is_king(piece):
                primitive_moves += self.generate_king_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
        pos_y = 0 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else 7
        if (
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE] and
            is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y][5]) and
            is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y][6])
        ):
            primitive_moves.append("0-0")
        if (
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][MoveType.LONG_CASTLE] and
            is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y][1]) and
            is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y][2]) and
            is_empty(self.matrix[pos_y][3])
        ):
            primitive_moves.append("0-0-0")
        return primitive_moves

    def generate_legal_moves(self) -> list[str]:
        legal_moves = []
        for move in self.generate_primitive_moves():
            copy_board = deepcopy(self)
            copy_board.implement_move(decode_move(move))
            if not copy_board.is_check():
                if move == "0-0":
                    start_y = 0 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else 7
                    if not copy_board.is_attacked(start_y, 5, get_opposite_color(self.current_turn_color)):
                        legal_moves.append(move)
                elif move == "0-0-0":
                    start_y = 0 if self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else 7
                    if not copy_board.is_attacked(start_y, 3, get_opposite_color(self.current_turn_color)):
                        legal_moves.append(move)
                else:
                    legal_moves.append(move)
        return legal_moves

    def is_attacked(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int, color: Color) -> list:
        original_turn_color = self.current_turn_color
        self.current_turn_color = color
        for move in self.generate_primitive_moves():
            move_data = decode_move(move)
            if move_data["type"] == MoveType.NORMAL:
                start_y, start_x = move_data["start_pos"]
                if move_data["end_pos"] == [pos_y, pos_x]:
                    if is_pawn(self.matrix[start_y][start_x]):
                        if abs(start_x - pos_x) == 1:
                            self.current_turn_color = original_turn_color
                            return True
                    else:
                        self.current_turn_color = original_turn_color
                        return True
        self.current_turn_color = original_turn_color
        return False

    def find_king(self, color: Color) -> list[int, int]:
        for y, rank in enumerate(self.matrix):
            for x, piece in enumerate(rank):
                if is_king(piece) and get_color(piece) == color:
                    return [y, x]
        return False

    def is_check(self):
        king_pos = self.find_king(self.current_turn_color)
        return self.is_attacked(*king_pos, get_opposite_color(self.current_turn_color))

    def generate_knight_legal_moves(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int) -> list[str]:
        legal_moves = []
        for delta_y, delta_x in KNIGHT_DELTAS:
            end_y = pos_y + delta_y
            end_x = pos_x + delta_x
            if (
                is_in_bounds(end_y, end_x) and
                get_color(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]) != self.current_turn_color
            ):
                legal_moves.append(encode_move({
                    "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                    "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                    "end_pos": [end_y, end_x]
                }))
        return legal_moves

    def generate_bishop_legal_moves(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int) -> list[str]:
        legal_moves = []
        for delta_y, delta_x in BISHOP_DELTAS:
            for i in range(1, 9):
                end_y = pos_y + i*delta_y
                end_x = pos_x + i*delta_x
                if (
                    not is_in_bounds(end_y, end_x) or
                    get_color(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]) == self.current_turn_color
                ):
                    break
                legal_moves.append(encode_move({
                    "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                    "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                    "end_pos": [end_y, end_x]
                }))
                if not is_empty(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]):
                    break
        return legal_moves

    def generate_rook_legal_moves(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int) -> list[str]:
        legal_moves = []
        for delta_y, delta_x in ROOK_DELTAS:
            for i in range(1, 9):
                end_y = pos_y + i*delta_y
                end_x = pos_x + i*delta_x
                if (
                    not is_in_bounds(end_y, end_x) or
                    get_color(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]) == self.current_turn_color
                ):
                    break
                legal_moves.append(encode_move({
                    "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                    "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                    "end_pos": [end_y, end_x]
                }))
                if not is_empty(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]):
                    break
        return legal_moves

    def generate_queen_legal_moves(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int) -> list[str]:
        return (
            self.generate_bishop_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x) +
            self.generate_rook_legal_moves(pos_y, pos_x)
        )

    def generate_king_legal_moves(self, pos_y: int, pos_x: int) -> list[str]:
        legal_moves = []
        for delta_y, delta_x in KING_DELTAS:
            end_y = pos_y + delta_y
            end_x = pos_x + delta_x
            if (
                is_in_bounds(end_y, end_x) and
                get_color(self.matrix[end_y][end_x]) != self.current_turn_color
            ):
                legal_moves.append(encode_move({
                    "type": MoveType.NORMAL,
                    "start_pos": [pos_y, pos_x],
                    "end_pos": [end_y, end_x]
                }))
        return legal_moves

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        output = ""
        for row in reversed(self.matrix):
            output += " ".join(row) + "\n"
        return output[:-1]
```

### console_ui.py

```
from board import *

game = Board()

def print_chess_board():
    new_array = []
    reversed_matrix = list(reversed(game.matrix))
    for i in range(8):
        new_array.append([str(i + 1), *reversed_matrix[i]])
    new_array.append([" ", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"])
    print("\n".join([" ".join(rank) for rank in new_array]))

while True:
    print_chess_board()
    if game.game_state == GameState.CHECKMATE:
        print("Checkmate!!")
        print(f"{turn} wins the game!!")
        break
    elif game.game_state == GameState.STALEMATE:
        print("Stalemate!! The game is a draw!")
        break
    turn = "White" if game.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE else "Black"
    move = input(f"{turn}!! Enter your move: ").lower().strip()
    game.play_move(move)
```

Edit 1:
There is small mistake in the interface, the numbering from 1 to 8 is written in inverse order.

Comment: If I play `b1c3` as first move as white, it actually moves black's knight from b8 to c6.

Comment: Sorry... the numbering from 1 to 8 is wrong... White is at the bottom and black is at the top... Uppercase charactar represent white and lowercase represent black...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't build everything on top of primitives**. Your current code is carefully done and
not difficult to follow. Its primary drawback is that nearly all of the logic
operates on primitive data types: pieces are letters; moves are stored as
strings (chess notation) that must be repeatedly decoded into a dict; the board
is a two-dimensional matrix; the castling data is a two-level dict; nearly all
methods stick their fingers directly into one of both of those data structures.
To advance this program to the next level of coding proficiency, you need to
stop performing all of the logic with primitive information types like this.

**Be generous in creating the data-objects your program needs**. Other
reviewers have already suggested a couple of data objects, such as `Pos` and
`Move`. I'm encouraging you to take that approach farther, both in terms of
additional data objects (such as `Piece`) and in terms of moving more of your
coding logic, helper utilities, and coding conveniences into those classes.
These data objects often serve as an interface between primitive types of
information (for example the string `e7e5`) and higher-level information like a
`Move` instance. The rest of your program will work with the higher-level
stuff, not the primitives.

**Start with some constants and enumerations**.

```
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass

FILE_TO_INDEX = dict((f, i) for i, f in enumerate('abcdefgh'))

class MoveType(Enum):
    NORMAL = 0
    SHORT_CASTLE = 1
    LONG_CASTLE = 2
    PAWN_PROMOTION = 3

class Color(Enum):
    NONE = 0
    WHITE = 1
    BLACK = 2

class PieceType(Enum):
    KING = 0
    QUEEN = 1
    ROOK = 2
    BISHOP = 3
    KNIGHT = 4
    PAWN = 5
```

**Define a `Piece` data object**. It might seem strange to have a class with a
single letter as its only attribute, but notice what you can do once you
introduce the concept of a `Piece`. Based on its symbol, it can compute its
`Color` and `PieceType`.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Piece:
    sym: str

    TYPES = dict(
        k = PieceType.KING,
        q = PieceType.QUEEN,
        r = PieceType.ROOK,
        b = PieceType.BISHOP,
        n = PieceType.KNIGHT,
        p = PieceType.PAWN,
    )

    @property
    def color(self):
        return Color.WHITE if self.sym.isupper() else Color.BLACK

    @property
    def type(self):
        return self.TYPES[self.sym.lower()]
```

**Define a `Move` data object**. A move has start and end positions, a type,
and sometimes a promoted piece. We can use a class method to support the
decoding of a primitive (chess notation) into a proper `Move` instance.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Pos:
    x: int
    y: int

@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Move:
    start: Pos = None
    end: Pos = None
    type: MoveType = MoveType.NORMAL
    promoted: Piece = None

    @classmethod
    def from_notation(cls, notation):
        # Handle castling.
        if notation == '0-0':
            return cls(type = MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE)
        elif notation == '0-0-0':
            return cls(type = MoveType.LONG_CASTLE)

        # Unpack notation: start file/row, end file/row, promoted piece.
        sf, sr, ef, er, _, pp = tuple((notation + '  ')[0:6])
        promoted = pp.strip() or None
        mtype = MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION if promoted else MoveType.NORMAL

        # Assemble Move and return.
        return cls(
            start = Pos(FILE_TO_INDEX[sf], int(sr) - 1),
            end = Pos(FILE_TO_INDEX[ef], int(er) - 1),
            type = mtype,
            promoted = promoted,
        )
```

**Using convenience variables to aid readability**. Notice the use of
convenience variables when unpacking the chess notation. Due to their
shortness, the variables could be cryptic in many situations. But in this case,
the method is simple enough and the comments provide enough context to keep
everything easy to read -- indeed the compactness of the variables aids that
readability. Those variable names also help to reinforce a naming convention
that I extended further in the class (properties to easily access position
parameters). And while working on another part of the program, I found that I
wanted `Move` instances to have other conveniences and helpers.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Move:
    ...

    @property
    def sx(self):
        return self.start.x

    @property
    def sy(self):
        return self.start.y

    @property
    def ex(self):
        return self.start.x

    @property
    def ey(self):
        return self.start.y

    @property
    def is_castle(self):
        return self.type in (MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE, MoveType.LONG_CASTLE)

    @property
    def indexes(self):
        return (self.sx, self.sy, self.ex, self.ey)
```

**Demonstration in the `Board` class**. Now that we have the data objects we
need, the logic in `Board` can operate at a higher level, working with the
attributes, properties, and conveniences provided by the data objects. In this
example, I will rewrite most of the `implement_move()` to illustrate the
difference that building on top of higher-level information can make.

**Delegate grubby details**. In addition to operating on richer types of data,
the `Board` class also needs to delegate its own low-level manipulations and
logic to helper methods. I ended up using one to implement a piece move on the
board matrix; another to check current color; and a couple more to set or get
castling data.

```
class Board:

    def do_move(self, sx, sy, ex, ey):
        piece = self.matrix[sy][sx]
        self.matrix[ey][ex] = piece
        self.matrix[sy][sx] = None
        return piece

    @property
    def is_white(self):
        return self.current_turn_color == Color.WHITE

    def disable_castle(self, *move_types):
        for mt in move_types:
            self.can_castle[self.current_turn_color][mt] = False 

    def castle_indexes(self, move_type):
        y = 0 if self.is_white else 7
        if move_type == MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE:
            return (y, 7, 5, 4, 6)
        else:
            return (y, 0, 3, 4, 2)
```

**Work with higher-order data and operations**. Finally, in `implement_move()`
we end up with less code, less logical complexity, and code that reads fairly
naturally.

```
class Board:

    def implement_move(self, mv):
        if mv.type == MoveType.PAWN_PROMOTION:
            # Move pawn.
            self.do_move(*mv.indexes)
            # Promote.
            pp = mv.promoted
            new_piece = Piece(pp.upper() if self.is_white else pp)
            self.matrix[mv.ey][mv.ex] = new_piece

        elif mv.is_castle:
            # Get indexes for y, rook start/end, king start/end.
            y, rs, re, ks, ke = self.castle_indexes(mv.type)
            # Move rook, then king.
            self.do_move(rs, y, re, y)
            self.do_move(ks, y, ke, y)
            # Disable.
            self.disable_castle(MoveType.SHORT_CASTLE, MoveType.LONG_CASTLE)

        else:
            # Move piece.
            piece = self.do_move(*mv.indexes)
            # Disable castle.
            if piece.type == PieceType.ROOK:
                self.disable_castle(mv.type)
            # En passant
            if piece.type == PieceType.PAWN:
                # Omitted in this demo.
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the so very concise and comprehensive review!

Answer (score 1):

Not exhaustive by any means but a few quick pointers:

Instead of constructing bidirectional dictionaries for files, you can just use a string with normal indexing and lookup. And instead of having an implicitly defined "move" dict and a bunch of helper methods, use dataclasses and python's built in magic-method machinery to make things more intuitive:

```
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass

FILE = 'abcdefgh'

class MoveType(Enum):
    NORMAL = 0
    SHORT_CASTLE = 1
    LONG_CASTLE = 2
    PAWN_PROMOTION = 3

"""Represents a position on the board"""
@dataclass
class Pos:
  x: int
  y: int

  """Encodes the position in chess notation"""
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{FILE[self.x]}{self.y + 1}'

"""Represents a chess move"""
@dataclass
class Move:
  type: MoveType
  start: Pos
  end: Pos

  """Encodes a move in chess notation"""
  # I'm just showing the simplest case here as an illustration:
  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.start}{self.end}'
    # See how this implicitly relies on Pos.__str__ defined above
```

Now your code is organized logically around the types of information you're representing and operations on those types, and you can build and show moves in a much more direct way:

```
m = Move(type=MoveType.NORMAL, start=Pos(0, 0), end=Pos(1, 1))
print(m)          # 'a1b2'
print(m.start.x)  # 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea... Definitely this extra piece of code will bury many redundant lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

I like @tzaman's suggestions, especially `dataclass`.

---

Here's a code organization detail:
bury methods like `get_color` within the Enum.

Consider replacing the `if`s in `get_opposite_color`
with a single subtraction.

You didn't use an Enum for the pieces, and that seems Fine.
If you *were* to choose the Enum path,
you'd have an opportunity to similarly
bury some helper methods.

---

```
def is_in_bounds(*nums: int):
    return all([0 <= num <= 7 for num in nums])
```

You went with a list-of-lists representation for the board.
That implies random reads to dereference lots of object pointers.
Python offers an alternative.
Consider representing the board as an array instead.

The numpy library is a bit heavyweight,
so I can understand reluctance to include it as a dependency,
that's fine. If you *do* choose to `import numpy`,
you could implement `is_in_bounds` as a fast
vectorized operation.

---

## dispatch via map

In `encode_move` you have the usual predictable `if`
encoding of the game's rules, cool.
There's four chunks of code in there.
Consider switching to `def move_normal`
plus three similar functions,
and dispatching in this way:

```
MOVE_ENCODING_MAP = {
    MoveType.NORMAL: move_normal,
    ...
}
def encode_move(move: dict) -> str:
    return MOVE_ENCODING_MAP[move["type"]](move)
```

That's not the only place you might want to use the technique.
For example later you dispatch on `is_knight`
to the nicely named `generate_knight_legal_moves`.

---

I like the various deltas,
especially how `QUEEN_DELTAS` is built up.

The names are perhaps a bit tedious.
Consider defining this instead:

```
PIECE_TO_DELTAS = {
    "b": [(1, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1)],
    ...
}
```

Also, the delta_{y,x} comments are helpful.
But we probably need it just once.
If a tuple like `(-1, 1)` is hard to interpret,
then consider using
[named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
or even
[dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

BTW, a `list` is a mutable container with arbitrary
number of elements that are the "same" kind of thing.
Prefer a `tuple` for a fixed number of elements
that are distinguished by their position.
Think of it as an immutable C struct.

---

For the rest, I will just say that a method
which is too long to read all of it without scrolling
is a method that is too long.
Good luck with the game!

Comment: Thanks for the review... I appreciate your idea regarding the use of enums to bury helper methods... I also like the dispatch via map idea, but I feel it is more of a overkill for `encode_move()`. But it is definitely a good idea for `generate_abc_legal_moves()`. Nonetheless... I appreciate you taking out time for this review...